# No module named 'lupa' in fake redis

Tags: python-3.x, fakeredis

When I was using `lock.release` from [`fakeredis`](https://pypi.org/project/fakeredis/0.4.2/) lib, I got below exception:

```
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/lock.py", line 111, in acquire
     if self.do_acquire(token):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/lock.py", line 258, in do_acquire
     client=self.redis))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2950, in __call__
     return client.evalsha(self.sha, len(keys), *args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2079, in evalsha
     return self.execute_command('EVALSHA', sha, numkeys, *keys_and_args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 667, in execute_command
     connection.send_command(*args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
     self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 590, in send_packed_command
     self._sock.sendall(item)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fakeredis/_server.py", line 808, in sendall
     self._parser.send(data)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fakeredis/_server.py", line 725, in _parse_commands
     self._process_command(fields)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fakeredis/_server.py", line 827, in _process_command
     result = self._run_command(func, sig, fields[1:], False)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fakeredis/_server.py", line 741, in _run_command
     result = func(*args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fakeredis/_server.py", line 2439, in evalsha
     return self.eval(script, numkeys, *keys_and_args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fakeredis/_server.py", line 2386, in eval
     from lupa import LuaRuntime, LuaError, as_attrgetter
 No module named 'lupa'
```

> *I didn't find a similar question (So far) so I just wanted to share the solution for those people who will face this exception in the future*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://pypi.org/project/fakeredis/),

> Although fakeredis is pure Python, you will need `lupa` if you want to run Lua scripts (this includes features like redis.lock.Lock, which are implemented in Lua). If you install `fakeredis` with `pip install fakeredis[lua]` it will be automatically installed.

**So:**

```
pip install fakeredis[lua]
```